# Code works on Anaconda but not on Python through cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I have code that runs over 7000 columns dataset with around 250k records

it works fine when I use Anaconda Spyder

but now I want to put this code to run based on Task Schedule

Therefore I am want to execute the code in cmd Command Prompt as

```
Python "c:\myfolder\predservice.py"
```

It didn't work as Task Schedule

I start tracing the problem by running the script on Python from within cmd

I got this error, which I did not get when I was running through Spyder

How can  I avoid such error

I thought it is because of the memory. when i select a subset of the dataset it runs fine but when I run the whole dataset i get this error

```
>>> df =pd.concat([df.drop('PreviousDRGs', 1), pd.get_dummies(df['PreviousDRGs'] .str.split(",", expand=True), prefix
 = 'PreviousDRGs').max(level=0, axis=1).asty pe(np.int8)], axis=1)


 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
 <module>   File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
 line 11616, in stat_func return self._agg_by_level(name, axis=axis,
 level=level, skipna=skipna)   


 File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
 line 10440, in _agg_by_level grouped = self.groupby(level=level,
 axis=axis, sort=False)   


 File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
 line 7894, in groupby **kwargs   



 File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py",
 line 2522, in groupby return klass(obj, by, **kwds)   



 File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py",
 line 363, in __init__ obj._consolidate_inplace()   



 File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
 line 5252, in _consolidate_inplace self._protect_consolidate(f)   



 File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
 line 5241, in _protect_consolidate result = f()   




 File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
 line 5250, in f self._data = self._data.consolidate()   



 File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py",
 line 932, in consolidate bm._consolidate_inplace()   





 File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py",
 line 937, in _consolidate_inplace self.blocks =
 tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))   




 File
 "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py",
 line 1913, in _consolidate list(group_blocks), dtype=dtype,
 _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate   



 File "C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py",
 line 3323, in _merge_blocks new_values = new_values[argsort]   
 numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with
 shape (4524, 1 38299) and data type uint8
>>>
```

Comment: Please repaste you traceback and format it as code. It is not readable like this.

Comment: Are the Python executable that you are calling in the command prompt and the Spyder application both part of the same python installation/environment?

Comment: @Xukrao I dont call executables. I call .py file

Comment: When you enter `Python "c:\myfolder\predservice.py"` in the command prompt you're calling python.exe and feeding it the .py file. The error traceback seems to indicate that this python executable is part of an installation in `C:\Users\decisionsupport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`. Is your Spyder application part of this same installation as well, or is it in a separate installation?

Comment: Just a guess but could it be that Anaconda uses a 64-bit python? Your error traceback shows that your Task Scheduler is running your .py script using a 32-bit python.

Comment: @Xukrao Spyder is not part of the installation. I am using vanilla Python3.7

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I think you are right. I have uninstalled the 32 version and installed the 64 version. things are working now. thx. if you put this as an answer i will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Anaconda may be using a 64-bit python. Your error traceback shows that your Task Scheduler is running your .py script using a 32-bit python. Either

1. replace your 32-bit python with a 64-bit version
2. or install a separate 64-bit python and tell Task Scheduler to use that to run
   your .py file.

Comment: Belongs as a comment.  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to activate your conda base in cmd before calling the script

```
call <path>\anaconda\Scripts\activate base
<path>\anaconda\python.exe <path>\scriptname.py
```